# The final value of my database corrupts after quick sort

Tags: c++, database, qsort

So I managed to write a program to store OpAmp data in a small database (10 pieces of data) and everything seems to be fine until I perform a quick sort, sorting by Slew Rate in ascending order. When I do this the final piece of data in my database comes back as a series of symbols unrelated to the data entered. This does not happen on the quick sort by Name. Anyone have any idea what is going wrong? Here is my code...

```
//File: Task1.cpp
//Title: Structured Programming in C++
//Created: 05/12/2012
//Author: Nicole ...
//ID Number: ...
//Accompanying Files: database.txt
//Description:A program which allows 
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

// the format of each of the elements in the database
struct OpAmps {
  char Name[20];  // the name of the op-amp (e.g. "741")
  unsigned int PinCount;  // the number of pins in the package
  double SlewRate;  // the slew rate in volts per microsecond
};

// the length of the fixed array to be used for database - must be at least one
// and no greater the maximum value allowed in an unsigned long (see the file limits.h)
#define DATABASE_MAX 10

// file used for the database
#define DATABASE_FILENAME "database.txt"

// function prototypes
void Enter(OpAmps&, unsigned long&);
void Save(OpAmps[], unsigned long);
void Load(OpAmps[], unsigned long&);
void Sort(OpAmps[], unsigned long);
void Display(OpAmps[], unsigned long);
void QuickSortName (OpAmps[], unsigned long);
void QuickSortSlewRate (OpAmps[], unsigned long);

// Control the entering, saving, loading, sorting and displaying of elements in the database
// Arguments: None
// Returns: 0 on completion
int main()
{
  OpAmps OpAmp[DATABASE_MAX];   // the database
  unsigned long database_length = 0;  // the number of elements in the database
  char UserInput;

  // loop until the user wishes to exit
  while (1) {

    // show the menu of options
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Op-amp database menu" << endl;
    cout << "--------------------" << endl;
    cout << "1. Enter a new op-amp into the database" << endl;
    cout << "2. Save the database to disk" << endl;
    cout << "3. Load the database from disk" << endl;
    cout << "4. Sort the database" << endl;
    cout << "5. Display the database" << endl;
    cout << "6. Exit from the program" << endl << endl;

    // get the user's choice
    cout << "Enter your option: ";
    cin >> UserInput;
    cout << endl;

    // act on the user's input
    switch(UserInput) {
      case '1':
            Enter(OpAmp[database_length], database_length);
         break;

      case '2':
            Save(OpAmp, database_length);
        break;

      case '3':
            Load(OpAmp, database_length);
        break;

      case '4':
            Sort(OpAmp, database_length);
        break;

      case '5':
            Display(OpAmp, database_length);
        break;

      case '6':
        return 0;

      default:
            cout << "Invalid Entry" << endl << endl;
        break;
    }
  }
}

void Enter(OpAmps& eOpAmp, unsigned long& database_length)
{
    cout<<"1) Enter Data"<<endl;

        if (database_length == DATABASE_MAX)
        {
            cout <<endl << "Database is full!!!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << endl << "Name of OpAmp: ";
            cin >> eOpAmp.Name;
            cout << endl << "Number of Pins on OpAmp: ";
            cin >> eOpAmp.PinCount;
            cout << endl << "Slew Rate of OpAmp: ";
            cin >> eOpAmp.SlewRate;
            cout << endl<< "All Items Added!" << endl << "Now Save Your Data!" << endl;
            database_length++;
        }
}

void Save(OpAmps sOpAmp[], unsigned long database_length)
{
    cout<<"2) Save Data"<<endl;
    fstream output_file; 
    output_file.open(DATABASE_FILENAME, ios::out);

    if (!output_file.good())
        {
            cout << "Error Loading File!!!" << endl;
            return;
        }
    else
        {
            int i;
            output_file << database_length<< endl<<endl;
            for(i=0;i<=database_length-1;i++)
        {
            output_file << sOpAmp[i].Name << endl; 
            output_file << sOpAmp[i].PinCount<< endl;
            output_file << sOpAmp[i].SlewRate;
        }
            cout << endl << "Data Saved" <<endl;
        }
    output_file.close();
}

void Load(OpAmps lOpAmp[], unsigned long& database_length)
{
    cout<<"3) Load Data"<<endl; 
    fstream input_file;
    input_file.open(DATABASE_FILENAME, ios::in);
    if (!input_file.good())
        {
            cout << "Error Loading File!!!" << endl;
            return;
        }
    else
        {
            input_file >> database_length;
            for(int i=0;i<=database_length-1;i++)
                {
                    input_file >> lOpAmp[i].Name; 
                    input_file >> lOpAmp[i].PinCount;
                    input_file >> lOpAmp[i].SlewRate;
                }
        }
    input_file.close();
}

void Sort(OpAmps qOpAmp[], unsigned long database_length)
{
  cout<<"4) Sort Data"<<endl;
  char UserInput;
  // show the menu of options
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Sorting options" << endl;
    cout << "---------------" << endl;
    cout << "1. To sort by name" << endl;
    cout << "2. To sort by slew rate" << endl;
    cout << "3. No sorting" << endl << endl;
    // get the user's choice of sorting operation required
    cout << "Enter your option: ";
    cin >> UserInput;
    // act on the user's input
    switch (UserInput) {
        case '1':
            cout <<"Sort By Name"<<endl;
            QuickSortName (qOpAmp, database_length);
        break;
        case '2':
            cout <<"Sort By Slew Rate"<<endl;
            QuickSortSlewRate (qOpAmp, database_length);
        break;
        case '3':
            cout <<"No Sort"<<endl;
        break;
        default:
            cout <<"Invalid Entry"<< endl;
            return;
        break;
    }
}

void QuickSortName (OpAmps nOpAmp[], unsigned long database_length)
{
    OpAmps temp;    // Local variable used to swap records
    for(int i=0; i<database_length; i++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<database_length; i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(nOpAmp[i].Name, nOpAmp[i+1].Name)>0)
            {
                temp = nOpAmp[i];
                nOpAmp[i] = nOpAmp[i+1];
                nOpAmp[i+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    Display (nOpAmp, database_length);
}
void QuickSortSlewRate (OpAmps rOpAmp[], unsigned long database_length)
{
    OpAmps temp;    // Local variable used to swap records
    for(int i=0; i<database_length; i++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<database_length; i++)
        {
            if(rOpAmp[i].SlewRate > rOpAmp[i+1].SlewRate)
            {
                temp = rOpAmp[i];
                rOpAmp[i] = rOpAmp[i+1];
                rOpAmp[i+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    Display (rOpAmp, database_length);
}


void Display(OpAmps dOpAmp[], unsigned long database_length)
{
    cout<<"5) Display Data"<<endl;
    if (database_length == 0)
    {
        cout<<endl<< "Database is Empty!!!" <<endl;
    }
    else
    {   
        cout <<endl<<database_length<<" items are in the database" << endl;
        for (unsigned long i = 0; i <= (database_length-1); i++)
        {
            cout << endl << "Database Entry Number: " << i+1<< endl;
            cout << "Name: " << dOpAmp[i].Name <<endl;
            cout << "PinCount: " << dOpAmp[i].PinCount<<endl;
            cout << "Slew Rate: " << dOpAmp[i].SlewRate<< endl <<endl;

        }
    }
}
```

After each piece of data you enter, select save, then enter the next piece, once you have entered as many items as you want, load the data, and then sort the data. You will see this issue. Any help would be amazing to iron out this bug!

Comment: Your sorting code uses `i` in both loops, so I can see this going out of range in the inner loop.  I highly suggest you check out the quick-sort algorithm a little closer.

Comment: Your "quick-sort" is actually a (sub-optimal) bubble sort (with serious bugs in it). Maybe look into using the built-in sorting facilities in C++ (e.g. `std::sort`)?

Comment: Hi, Thank you Moo-Juice for your answer, I changed these so one is an i and one is a j and this hasn't alleviated the problem. As stated the sort by Name works but I fail to see the difference between this and the sort by Slew Rate.  Thank you!

Comment: Hi Cameron, I didn't realise this was a bubble sort not a quick sort but either way i just need it to do a simple sort. I don't want to change too much of the code now as I am very new to C++ as it is. Could you offer any advice for optimising what I have now for me to iron out those bugs? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Sorry, have edited my comment to show the actual problem - you're exceeding the bounds of your OpAmps array during your sort.

Comment: After adding your code beerboy the last item is still not working correctly and it is causing the last item i add to the database to come back as Name: series of symbols PinCount: Large number not what was entered SlewRate: large negative number not what was entered

Comment: Found another possible error in your `Save` function, see my updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately that still hasn't solved the issue and it is strange as it is only the last entry each time and only the sort by slew rate :/

Answer (score 2):

```
void QuickSortSlewRate (OpAmps rOpAmp[], unsigned long database_length)
{
    OpAmps temp;    // Local variable used to swap records
    for(int i=0; i<database_length; i++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<database_length; i++)
        {
```

Your nested loops use the same variable (i).

```
if(rOpAmp[i].SlewRate > rOpAmp[i+1].SlewRate)
```

And you're stepping off the end of your array here when i equals (database_length - 1).

```
void Save(OpAmps sOpAmp[], unsigned long database_length)
{
    ...
        for(i=0;i<=database_length-1;i++)
        {
            output_file << sOpAmp[i].Name << endl; 
            output_file << sOpAmp[i].PinCount<< endl;
            output_file << sOpAmp[i].SlewRate;         // **missing endl**
        }
```

And your file format may be corrupted - there's a missing `endl` in your Save function.

Since you're using C++, why not use `std::sort` instead of a slow bubble sort?

```
// compare function for std::sort
bool CompareSlewRate(const OpAmps& a, const OpAmps& b)
{
    return a.SlewRate < b.SlewRate;
}

void QuickSortSlewRate (OpAmps rOpAmp[], unsigned long database_length)
{
    std::sort(rOpAmp, rOpAmp + database_length, CompareSlewRate);
    Display (rOpAmp, database_length);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help beerboy! 
Would I replace this code in place of my function now then? And Then still call the function QuickSortSlewRate as I already have? I haven't used std: sort before or bool. I will give this a go and see how it handles the code! Would it be similar if I were to also change my sortbyname to do sort but in alphabetical order? Thanks!

Comment: yes - you just need to add `#include <algorithm>` to the top of your source file.

Comment: This hasn't solved my problem of the last piece of data being corrupt